Python (mypy) incompatible types when working with typeVars and a callable argument
I am currently trying to create a requests wrapper that is typed and allows you to provide a response handler. This response handler, might alter the return value of the http request.
Unfortunately I am not able to overcome some typing issues (I am fairly new to typing with python). This seems like a general issue or misunderstanding on my side, which is why I am creating this post. I have read into several concepts like Generics, or Protocols, yet I was not able to create a working solution, nor I think I fully understand which solution might be the best for this.
Here is my example code:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar

from requests import Response

_T = TypeVar("_T", default=Response)


def identity(response: Response) -> Response:
    return response


def extract_text(response: Response) -> str:
    return response.text


class HTTPRequestsAPI:

    def fake_request(self, response_handler: Callable[[Response], _T] = identity) -> _T:
        response = Response()
        processed_response = response_handler(response)
        return processed_response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    request_api = HTTPRequestsAPI()
    resp = request_api.fake_request()
    print(type(resp))

    resp_text = request_api.fake_request(response_handler=extract_text)
    print(type(resp_text))

I can run the main without any issues and get the following output (types), which are as expected:
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
<class 'str'>

When I try to run mypy, I get an error, and I do not understand why this happens, as I assume that the types should be correctly inferred:
error: Incompatible default for argument "response_handler" (default has type "Callable[[Response], Response]", argument has type "Callable[[Response], _T]")  [assignment]

What am I not getting here, might this be a mypy related issue? I have not yet tried another type-checker like "pyright". Thank you very much for you help!
**I am using python = 3.13 and mypy = 1.13.0 in this example. I have also tried without a "default" for the TypeVar, but this made no difference and I thought a default might help the typer.

This is a known issue with mypy. TL;DR you'll want to use typing.overload to create two signatures: one where the parameter is specified and one where it isn't.

The above comment is on point. FTR, Pyright has better support for this pattern.

@Gaberocksall if have tried to implement your suggestion and would the correct way to have 3 methods as follows (mypy does not allow a single overload as it throws an error):

fake_request(self, response_handler: Callable[[Response], _T]) -> _T,
fake_request(self) -> Response,
fake_request(self, response_handler=identity),

and the implementation goes in (3) and overload for (1,2)? If so I can add this as answer.

@InSync I will install pyright and test this, if it works I might provide an answer containing a pyright version and mypy version

@InSync, @Gaberocksal: I have provided an answer including both of your suggestions, I hope this is fine! I got this working now both with mypy and typing.overload as well as using pyright (no changes required)

@STerliakov it indeed seems similar. The other thread is lacking the information that pyright can handle this and therefore it is a solution to switch to pyright. For me this was very helpful.

As stated by @Gaberocksall in the comments, the above problem is mypy specific (see https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737). An option is to stick with mypy and use typing.overload.
I have created an example that implements the same behavior but is accepted by mypy:
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, overload

from requests import Response

_T = TypeVar("_T", default=Response)


def identity(response: Response) -> Response:
    return response


def extract_text(response: Response) -> str:
    return response.text


class HTTPRequestsAPI:

    @overload
    def fake_request(self, response_handler: Callable[[Response], _T]) -> _T:
        ...

    @overload
    def fake_request(self) -> Response:
        ...

    def fake_request(self, response_handler=identity):
        response = Response()
        processed_response = response_handler(response)
        return processed_response


if __name__ == "__main__":
    request_api = HTTPRequestsAPI()
    resp = request_api.fake_request()
    print(type(resp))

    resp_text = request_api.fake_request(response_handler=extract_text)
    print(type(resp_text))


On the other side, @InSync mentionend in the comments that a possible solution is to switch to pyright, as pyright will parse the posted code without any errors (I can verify this).
In summary, this might be a personal perference, but I will switch to pyright to avoid "unneccessary" overloads. In my "real" project this would blow up the code base and make it quite unreadable in my opinion.
Many Thanks for the help provided in the comments!
